# Formatting from ISO-8859-1 to Windows-1251

Tags: text-processing, unicode, character-encoding

I want to fix the encoding in a string "Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà" and get the correct `UTF-8` string "Перепрошить Сыроежкина".
[This](http://www.online-decoder.com/ru) website told me that I need to convert from `ISO-8859-1` to `Windows-1251` to get the correct result, however when I try to use `iconv` for this I get this error:

```bsh
$ echo 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t windows-1251 -
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
```

What I also do not understand is why I need to convert the string to `Windows-1251` when I want to get the result in `UTF-8`.

Edit:
I also tried to use `enconv`, however the result was unsatisfactory as well.

```bsh
$ echo 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' | enca -L ru -
Universal transformation format 8 bits; UTF-8
  Doubly-encoded to UTF-8 from ISO-8859-5
$ echo 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' | enconv -L ru -x UTF-8 -
Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà
$ echo 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' | enconv -L ru -x windows-1251 -
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string seems to be double-encoded: first the original Windows-1251 has been mis-interpreted as ISO-8859-1, then those mis-interpreted characters are themselves turned into their UTF-8 equivalents.

The fact that you can have the "wrong" text as visible characters along with the "correct" text indicates your system works in UTF-8 or some other Unicode character set, and that the string has been converted to Unicode in its mis-interpreted form.

Try decoding it this way:

```
echo 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 | iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8
Перепрошить Сыроежкина
```

If those characters were actually in their native 8-bit encoding, the string would be displayed something like this on an UTF-8 system: "����������� ����������". Any ISO-8859-1 (or any 8-bit character set) characters with the high bit set are likely to produce an "invalid encoding" result when interpreted as UTF-8. Unicode has a special display symbol, "�", for "this character has been encoded in a broken way".

If your system was actually using ISO-8859-1, you would see the string as 'Ïåðåïðîøèòü Ñûðîåæêèíà' - but then it would be impossible to display "Перепрошить Сыроежкина" in the same terminal window, because ISO-8859-1 does not include Cyrillics at all.

The website you linked probably sees the incoming string as UTF-8, and assumes that this conversion was just a part of the communication between the browser and the web server, and just identifies the other misinterpretation.