# Dump file conversion with iconv

Tags: files, dump

I tried to convert the dump file with iconv. The command that I used:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 |
  iconv -f windows-1251 -t utf-8
```

Unfortunately, it converts to the unreadable letters: `ГЋГЎГєГїГўГ«ГїГҐГІГ±Гї Г­Г ГЎГ®Г° Г¬Г®Г¤ГҐГ°Г ГІГ®Г°Г®Гў`. It works correctly if it is only one phrase.
From other thread I understood that the dump file might contain both text and binary data, and trying to interpret the binary data parts as text would most likely result in unreadable junk.

I tried to convert SQL dump file from web forum with unknown coding to utf-8. It works correctly if it is only one phrase like in this thread: [Formatting from ISO-8859-1 to Windows-1251](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629040/formatting-from-iso-8859-1-to-windows-1251). And it did not work for the file.

Comment: What is this dump file? Why you try to convert the code page?

Comment: Well what you're doing is explicitly wrong: you're converting to iso-8859-1, and knowing it is iso-8859-1, you then treat the file as win-1251, which simply is a different encoding. So, whyever you're doing this, it's broken by design. You will have to tell us what you're actually trying to achieve. How did you come up with this? Is very very strange.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried to convert SQL dump file from web forum with unknown coding to utf-8. It works correctly if it is only one phrase like in this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629040/formatting-from-iso-8859-1-to-windows-1251/729808?noredirect=1#comment1383972_729808. And it did not work for the file.

Comment: Please be sure to add all new information to the question. Replying in the comment section is discouraged because contributors would need to read the entire comment section (which is cumbersome), the comment section has only limited formatting tools, and comments are subject to removal be moderators without notice.